# Uncommited work exception in Queuable with Callback and Rollback

Tags: callout, asynchronous, queue, queueable-interface, transaction

Is there a way to do all that

1. Do Callout in Queueable
2. Do Dml based on the Callout result
3. Catch errors in 1 and 2.
4. Rollback 1, 2 on error
5. Report error via email and log in Custom object

without running into

> common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: You have uncommitted work
>   pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

This is how my code looks like:

```
public class MyQueue implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        try {
            List<SObject> result = getDataViaCallout();

            ...

            insert result; 
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            sendEmail(ex);
            insert new ErrorLog__c(Cause__c = ex.getMessage());

            Database.rollback(sp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the instruction

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
```

makes a DML, then you can't do a callout after that. You just need to do your callout in a separate context.

Comment: I think that is right based on this article:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC you're both right. No need to think it over.